# Webpack code splitting impacts web performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundle, code-splitting

I have a React/Node + SSR application, I am trying to create a production build, I have managed to do that but the problem is that the files that I have in the build are too large.
I use latest version of react + webpack 4.
Here is my webpack configuration:

clientConfig.js

```
const path = require('path');
const common = require('./webpack.common-config');

const clientConfig = {
  ...common,
  mode: 'production',
  name: 'client',
  target: 'web',
  devtool: false,
  entry: {
    client: [
      '@babel/polyfill',
      './src/client.js'
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          chunks: 'all',
          name: 'vendor',
          test: module => /node_modules/.test(module.resource),
          enforce: true
        },
        common: {
          chunks: 'all',
          name: 'client'
        }
      },
    },
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
  }
};

module.exports = clientConfig;
```

serverConfig.js

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const path = require('path');
const common = require('./webpack.common-config');

const serverConfig = {
  ...common,
  mode: 'production',
  name: 'server',
  target: 'node',
  devtool: false,
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: {
    server: ['@babel/polyfill', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'server.js')],
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    }
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js"
  },
  node: {
    console: false,
    global: false,
    process: false,
    Buffer: false,
    __filename: false,
    __dirname: false,
  },
};

module.exports = serverConfig;
```

commonConfig.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

const common = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
        query: {
          presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env', {loose: true, modules: false}],
            "@babel/preset-react"
          ],
          plugins: [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
          ]
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            },
            'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "styles.css",
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()]
  },
};

module.exports = common;
```

And another file which basically merges the client and the server config.

I run `npm run build` after that I run `webpack -p --mode=production --optimize-minimize && node ./build/server.js`

I get the following warning:

```
    WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
    This can impact web performance.
    Assets: 
      vendor.js (667 KiB)
    
    WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
    Entrypoints:
      client (928 KiB)
          vendor.js
          styles.css
          client.js
```

Any advice or idea for the above size warning would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I recommend that you try `core-js` instead of `babel/pollyfill` this can help you to reduce your bundle size.

Also, I recommend that you try dynamic importing with `react-loadable` which supports SSR. there are different strategies for splitting your code. you can read more [here](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable)(most important one)

In case you are using CSS frameworks such as bootstrap you should only use parts that you need and avoid importing all of them. there is a tool for purging unused CSS named purgecss but use it with caution and you have to know what are you doing.

In case you are using libraries such as lodash or material-ui you should import your module specifically to avoid importing all the packages into your bundle.

exp:
`import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'`

`npm dedup` or `yarn dedup` can help to remove duplicate dependencies inside bundle.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will look into the tools from above to see if I can do something to improve my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get some reduction through adjusting your babel configuration. For instance, specifying some options for the "preset-env", such as [bugfixes](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#bugfixes), `targets` if you don't have support older browsers, and using `corejs` polyfills instead of `babel/polyfill`.

```
"@babel/preset-env", {
  "targets": {
    "browsers": [
      "last 2 years"
    ]
  },
  "bugfixes": true,
  "useBuiltIns": "entry",  // experiment with "entry" vs. "usage"
  "corejs": 3
...
```

Depending on your codebase, the [babel-plugin-transform-runtime](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#docsNav) may help too. I had some projects where it made a substantial difference, but other where it hasn't.

```
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
{
  "corejs": 3,
  "version": "7.9.2"
}
```

Additional options for Webpack include using the [webpack-cdn-plugin](https://github.com/shirotech/webpack-cdn-plugin). This can greatly reduce your vendor bundle size. Of course, users will still have to download those same libraries, but they will be cached and don't need to re-downloaded every time your bundle changes or updates.

A little additional savings can be had by specifying `runtimeChunk: true`, and optionally inlining that chunk in your index.html with

```
new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  inlineSource: 'runtime~.+[.]js',
  ...
```

and the [html-webpack-inline-source-plugin](https://github.com/dustinjackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can split files to lower size to remove  warning using [splitChunks](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/):

```
optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        minSize: 10000,
        maxSize: 250000,
      }
    }
```

Check more for [minSize](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksminsize) and [maxSize](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksmaxsize).

If you want to disable the warning, you can do it using [performance](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/performance)

```
performance: {
  hints: false
}
```

or remove warning for certain size limit like 1 MB:

```
performance: {
  maxAssetSize: 1000000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to switch to Next.js so all of this is not necessary anymore.